# Adding a profile to user in django

Tags: python, django, django-users

Following this :

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html#onetoone

I am having some trouble with this call:

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
```

In their example I am guessing this works as is on the signup of a new account because the Profile in their example has all fields that can be blank and null.  In my case my profile I am trying to maintain here is called:

```
class APOUser(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    institution =  models.ForeignKey("mainpage.InstitutionMember", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    gender = models.ForeignKey("mainpage.GenderTable", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    on_site_status = models.ForeignKey("mainpage.SiteStatus", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    refer_to_as = models.TextField(max_length = 30, blank=True) #if the above is custom
    room_preference  = models.ForeignKey("housing.Room", on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Which has references to ultimately what will be drop downs to select form a form (populated by another table with defaults).   So do I remove the @reciever and then just have the users fill out the profile separately somehow after they signup and confirm their account?

I tried to mix my signup form with the profile form... but kept getting an anonmyous user object had no attribute object apouser in the views.py when I try to mix the signup forms and profile forms:

```
 def signup(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
        profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST, instance=request.user.apouser)

        if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
            user = form.save(commit=False)
            user.is_active = False
            user.save()
            profile_form.save()
            current_site = get_current_site(request)
            mail_subject = 'Activate your APO account.'
            message = render_to_string('acc_active_email.html', {
                'user': user,
                'domain': current_site.domain,
                'uid':urlsafe_base64_encode(force_bytes(user.pk)),
                'token':account_activation_token.make_token(user),
            })
            to_email = form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            email = EmailMessage(
                        mail_subject, message, to=[to_email]
            )
            email.send()
            return redirect('plsactivate')
            #return HttpResponse('Please confirm your email address to complete the registration')
            #form.save()
            #username = form.cleaned_data.get('username')
            #raw_password = form.cleaned_data.get('password1')
            #user = authenticate(username=username, password=raw_password)
            #login(request, user)
            #return redirect('/')
    else:
        form = SignUpForm()        
        profile_form = ProfileForm(instance=request.user.apouser) #<-- error here
    return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form, 'profile_form': profile_form})
    #return render(request, 'signup.html', {'form': form})
```

So not sure the proper way to go about what I need.  I have my regular user default with the basic stuff the default django signup comes up with. THen I have the APOUser with extra stuff (usually filled out in a profile) but not sure where/how to get users to fill that out.

On signup gives me the anonymous user error

After signup doesn't let the @reciever work because none of the APOUuser stuff is filled out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, remove the receiver - although it's not the cause of this specific problem, it will cause issues as soon as you fix that

The reason for your error is as it says: since you don't have a logged in user yet, you don't have a profile either. But you don't need one; there is no need to pass an instance argument there.

What you *do* need to do is to set the user on the result of saving the profile form - in just the she way as you set is_active on the result of saving the user form.

So:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignUpForm(request.POST)
    profile_form = ProfileForm(request.POST,)

    if form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
        user = form.save(commit=False)
        user.is_active = False
        user.save()
        profile = profile_form.save(commit=False)
        profile.user = user
        profile.save()
        ...
else:
    form = SignUpForm()        
    profile_form = ProfileForm()
...
```

Comment: man you are so freaking good at this.  This fixed it and I see the right stuff on the form during registration!  Woo hoo!  I have never attempted this in Django before so this is all great stuff ty so much